# How to call endpoint.select() in RTK query with an argument to retrieve cached data (within another selector)?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an endpoint which accepts a parameter and I'm trying to access the cached data using `endpoint.select()` in a redux slice. The problem is i cant figure out how to pass in the cache key. I've done the following:

```
export const selectProductsResult = (storeId) =>
   storeApi.endpoints.listProductsByStore.select(storeId);
```

This works fine if I use it within a component like this:

```
const currentStoreProducts = useSelector(selectProductResult(currentStoreId))
```

What I don't understand is how I can use this in another selector, for example this does not work:

```
 const selectCurrentProducts = createSelector((selectCurrentStoreId), currentStoreId 
     => selectProductResult(currentStoreId)
```

If I try to use this in a component like so:

```
const currentProducts = useSelector(selectCurrentProducts)
```

The value obtained is a memoized function. I've played around quite a bit and can't seem to build the desired selector.

Comment: I just wanted to add: if you want to use this in a component anyways, it's most likely a better idea to use the `useQuery` hooks for that data instead of `useSelector` with a selector from the endpoint. If you want to abstract it out, move it into a custom hook.

Comment: I'm migrating a large number of selectors over to rtk-query, the goal was to supply existing selectors but just swap out the api layer as a start, but there are some dependent queries. Sounds like most of them will need to be converted to hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `someEndpoint.select()` generates a new selector function that is specialized to look up the data for that cache key.  Loosely put, imagine it looks like this:

```js
const createEndpointSelector = (cacheKey) => {
  return selectorForCacheKey = () => {
    return state.api.queries['someEndpointName'][cacheKey];
  }
}

const selectDataForPikachu = createEndpointSelector('pikachu');
```

So, you need to call `someEndpoint.select()` with the actual cache key itself, and it returns a new selector that knows how to retrieve the data for that cache key:

```js
const selectDataForPikachu = apiSlice.endpoints.getPokemon.select('pikachu');

// later, in a component
const pikachuData = useSelector(selectDataForPikachu);
```

Comment: So in my case 'pikachu' is a dynamic value which is coming from another endpoint.select(). Is there any way to create a selector which returns the data using the result of another endpoint.select() function as its cache key? I know i can do this in a hook, but would like to plug data into existing selectors.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely feasible atm - you'd have to pass in `selectOtherEndpointData` as an "input selector" and call `thisEndpoint.select()` inside the output function... but that selector in turn requires the _entire_ Redux root state as its argument, which means that this selector wouldn't memoize correctly ever.

Comment: @DannyMoshe, were you able to send dynamic value to the `select` method?