# RTK Query — correct approach for creating endpoint data selectors

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I've been playing a bit with RTK Query and I was wondering how to correctly pick data from an endpoint and returning that data filtered (or somehow updated)

I ended up making this to work

```
export const selectGroupAvailableAssessments = (cacheKey) => {
  return rtkQueryApi.endpoints.getGroupAvailableAssessments.select(cacheKey);
};
// returns object with status, endpointName, data, error, isLoading, etc

export const selectGroupAvailableAssessmentsByAssessmentId = (cacheKey, assessmentId) => createSelector(
  selectGroupAvailableAssessments(cacheKey),
  (availableAssessments) => {
    if (!availableAssessments.data) return null;
    const { data } = availableAssessments;

    return data.find((item) => item.id === assessmentId);
  },
);
// returns the selector "data" assessments filtered by id
```

The in the component

```
const assessmentById = useSelector(selectGroupAvailableAssessmentsByAssessmentId(cacheKey, assessmentId));
```

Is this the correct approach for creating selectors in RTK Query? I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Used these links as reference
[How to use RTK query selector with an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724261/how-to-use-rtk-query-selector-with-an-argument)

https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/rtk-query-best-practices-e0296d1679e6

[How to call endpoint.select() in RTK query with an argument to retrieve cached data (within another selector)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71432769/how-to-call-endpoint-select-in-rtk-query-with-an-argument-to-retrieve-cached-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally just use the `useGetGroupAvailableAssessmentsQuery` hook - you can combine that with `selectFromResult`.

```js
const selectFiltered = createSelector(
  result => result.data,
  (_, assessmentId) => assessmentId,
  (data, assessmentId) => {
     return data.find((item) => item.id === assessmentId);
  }
)

const result = useGetGroupAvailableAssessmentsQuery(something, {
  selectFromResult(result) {
    return { ...result, data: selectFiltered(result, assessmentId) }
  }
})
```

Comment: I want to avoid reusing the original `useGetGroupAvailableAssessmentsQuery` that why I thought about just getting the data with a selector. I've also got adviced to use `createEntityAdapter` since I just want to get the `assessments` entity by its id :).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? Those selectors are really meant to be used when you are not in a React component - if you are in a component, you really should use the hooks.

Comment: The hook is a bit verbose due to the `options` object that I'm using and I was wondering if using a selector was a better approach. However your solution will work well depending the case. Thank you for the effort mantining the project! I love having several options.

Comment: You could have a global variable with the full options object if that helps you abstract it better? :)

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't thought a lot about those kind of abstractions since I'm just trying to figure out how to replace some unnecessary thunks with queries hehe. Thanks for your pathience.

Comment: Works like a charm by the way!